# From what point is a relationship considered haram?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, relationships

My question is, is being in a relationship fine if there is nothing haram in it but just a tag. We do nothing haram, nor meet but it's just that there's this relationship tag. Also please let me know from what point a relationship is considered haram.

Comment: You don't meet? So, you just call yourself as having a relationship with someone you haven't met and don't meet? What does it mean?

Comment: @TheZ I think she refers to meeting in person.

Comment: In Islam there's a term called mahram and any mahram is a person one is not allwoed to marry any other person is a non-mahram and for interactions of people of the two different genders which are non-Mahrams there are limitations. Therefore any kind of relationship apart from marriage is not allowed between them.

Answer (score 0):

Because sooner or later you will hold hands, dance, and she or he will try to kiss you this is haram before marriage. EVEN Friendship between males and females in Islam is discouraged. This is mainly because, as pointed out in an earlier reply, a platonic relationship between the opposite sexes is usually not possible. ... So in order to avoid future sentimental issues, it's best to not befriend one from the opposite sex. I wouldn’t risk It and if you really want to have love in the future you should make the dua of istikharah. Allah knows best